# Is the smallest unit of Ether 10^-18?

Tags: ether

How can this be checked? Is the code public ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. And it's called Wei.
there're several sub units on ETH and the smallest one is WEI which is equal to 10^-18 ETH

you can get to know about all the sub units with there value from here,
https://etherchain.org/tools/unitConverter

help yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the code is public:

```
const (
    Wei   = 1
    GWei  = 1e9
    Ether = 1e18
)
```

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a1f16bc74c7efb593db2982c92222d1e4a201c25/params/denomination.go#L24